# New version of Nswag generates incompatible data types

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, swagger, nswag

I have a **CMD** script that uses "nswag swagger2csclient" to generate a client for communicating with another API. It has worked before but once it used a newer version of Nswag things started going wrong.

The code looks like this:

```
// Controller method
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<CarViewModel>), 200)]
public async Task<ObjectResult> GetCars()

//Generated result with an older version of Nswag
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<CarViewModel>> GetCars();

//Generated result with an newer version of Nswag
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<CarViewModel>> GetCars();
```

The use of **Generic.ICollection** is incompatible with my own code and it would be tedious work to change all data types so I need Nswag to generate **ObjectModel.ObservableCollection** like it did in the older version.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can change this default with the /ArrayType:Collection param

See https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/wiki/CSharpGeneratorSettings